# Pig load: deprecated property fs.default.name

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have installed Hadoop 2.6.5 and I just have installed Pig 0.16 in the same machine. I ran pig and then I loaded a file using 
`a = load '/user/hduser/input/palabras.txt';` and I got this INFO `INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS` but I am wondering why this message appeared if I have already changed that property in core-site.xml file?

I hope to be clear, please let me know if another information is required. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to with your `core-site.xml`. 
This is an issue with Pig.

Pig's [`HExecutionEngine.java`](https://apache.googlesource.com/pig/+/release-0.16.0/src/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/executionengine/HExecutionEngine.java#79) contains this deprecated property `fs.default.name`.

```
public static final String FILE_SYSTEM_LOCATION = "fs.default.name";
```

This will be fixed in the upcoming versions. Refer [PIG-2768](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2768).